# How to convert tf.layer_norm to julia?

Tags: python, tensorflow, julia

I'm trying to convert tensorflow code to julia but I didn't understand how `layer_norm` function works.

I'm trying to convert that part:

```
output = tf.contrib.layers.layer_norm(attn_out + h, begin_norm_axis=-1,
                                              scope='LayerNorm')
```

shape of the tensor `attn_out + h` is `( qlen,bsz,d_model )` and when I downloaded the trained model, variables gamma and beta have shape  `(d_model,)`. Also, output of `nn.moments` should have shape `[qlen,bsz,1]`. `layer_norm` function calls `batch_norm` function with these parameters:

```
add_arg_scope
def layer_norm(inputs,
               center=True,
               scale=True,
               activation_fn=None,
               reuse=None,
               variables_collections=None,
               outputs_collections=None,
               trainable=True,
               begin_norm_axis=1,
               begin_params_axis=-1,
               scope=None):
  """Adds a Layer Normalization layer.
  Based on the paper:
    "Layer Normalization"
    Jimmy Lei Ba, Jamie Ryan Kiros, Geoffrey E. Hinton
    https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.06450.
  Can be used as a normalizer function for conv2d and fully_connected.
  Given a tensor `inputs` of rank `R`, moments are calculated and normalization
  is performed over axes `begin_norm_axis ... R - 1`.  Scaling and centering,
  if requested, is performed over axes `begin_params_axis .. R - 1`.
  By default, `begin_norm_axis = 1` and `begin_params_axis = -1`,
  meaning that normalization is performed over all but the first axis
  (the `HWC` if `inputs` is `NHWC`), while the `beta` and `gamma` trainable
  parameters are calculated for the rightmost axis (the `C` if `inputs` is
  `NHWC`).  Scaling and recentering is performed via broadcast of the
  `beta` and `gamma` parameters with the normalized tensor.
  The shapes of `beta` and `gamma` are `inputs.shape[begin_params_axis:]`,
  and this part of the inputs' shape must be fully defined.
  Args:
    inputs: A tensor having rank `R`. The normalization is performed over axes
      `begin_norm_axis ... R - 1` and centering and scaling parameters are
      calculated over `begin_params_axis ... R - 1`.
    center: If True, add offset of `beta` to normalized tensor. If False, `beta`
      is ignored.
    scale: If True, multiply by `gamma`. If False, `gamma` is not used. When the
      next layer is linear (also e.g. `nn.relu`), this can be disabled since the
      scaling can be done by the next layer.
    activation_fn: Activation function, default set to None to skip it and
      maintain a linear activation.
    reuse: Whether or not the layer and its variables should be reused. To be
      able to reuse the layer scope must be given.
    variables_collections: Optional collections for the variables.
    outputs_collections: Collections to add the outputs.
    trainable: If `True` also add variables to the graph collection
      `GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES` (see tf.Variable).
    begin_norm_axis: The first normalization dimension: normalization will be
      performed along dimensions `begin_norm_axis : rank(inputs)`
    begin_params_axis: The first parameter (beta, gamma) dimension: scale and
      centering parameters will have dimensions
      `begin_params_axis : rank(inputs)` and will be broadcast with the
        normalized inputs accordingly.
    scope: Optional scope for `variable_scope`.
  Returns:
    A `Tensor` representing the output of the operation, having the same
    shape and dtype as `inputs`.
  Raises:
    ValueError: If the rank of `inputs` is not known at graph build time,
      or if `inputs.shape[begin_params_axis:]` is not fully defined at
      graph build time.
  """
  with variable_scope.variable_scope(
      scope, 'LayerNorm', [inputs], reuse=reuse) as sc:
    inputs = ops.convert_to_tensor(inputs)
    inputs_shape = inputs.shape
    inputs_rank = inputs_shape.ndims
    if inputs_rank is None:
      raise ValueError('Inputs %s has undefined rank.' % inputs.name)
    dtype = inputs.dtype.base_dtype
    if begin_norm_axis < 0:
      begin_norm_axis = inputs_rank + begin_norm_axis
    if begin_params_axis >= inputs_rank or begin_norm_axis >= inputs_rank:
      raise ValueError('begin_params_axis (%d) and begin_norm_axis (%d) '
                       'must be < rank(inputs) (%d)' %
                       (begin_params_axis, begin_norm_axis, inputs_rank))
    params_shape = inputs_shape[begin_params_axis:]
    if not params_shape.is_fully_defined():
      raise ValueError(
          'Inputs %s: shape(inputs)[%s:] is not fully defined: %s' %
          (inputs.name, begin_params_axis, inputs_shape))
    # Allocate parameters for the beta and gamma of the normalization.
    beta, gamma = None, None
    if center:
      beta_collections = utils.get_variable_collections(variables_collections,
                                                        'beta')
      beta = variables.model_variable(
          'beta',
          shape=params_shape,
          dtype=dtype,
          initializer=init_ops.zeros_initializer(),
          collections=beta_collections,
          trainable=trainable)
    if scale:
      gamma_collections = utils.get_variable_collections(
          variables_collections, 'gamma')
      gamma = variables.model_variable(
          'gamma',
          shape=params_shape,
          dtype=dtype,
          initializer=init_ops.ones_initializer(),
          collections=gamma_collections,
          trainable=trainable)
    # By default, compute the moments across all the dimensions except the one with index 0.
    norm_axes = list(range(begin_norm_axis, inputs_rank))
    mean, variance = nn.moments(inputs, norm_axes, keep_dims=True)
    # Compute layer normalization using the batch_normalization function.
    # Note that epsilon must be increased for float16 due to the limited
    # representable range.
    variance_epsilon = 1e-12 if dtype != dtypes.float16 else 1e-3
    outputs = nn.batch_normalization(
        inputs,
        mean,
        variance,
        offset=beta,
        scale=gamma,
        variance_epsilon=variance_epsilon)
    outputs.set_shape(inputs_shape)
    if activation_fn is not None:
      outputs = activation_fn(outputs)
    return utils.collect_named_outputs(outputs_collections, sc.name, outputs)
```

However none of these tensors `(gamma,beta,mean,variance)` satisfy the input restrictions of `batch_norm`:

```
@tf_export("nn.batch_normalization")
def batch_normalization(x,
                        mean,
                        variance,
                        offset,
                        scale,
                        variance_epsilon,
                        name=None):
  r"""Batch normalization.
  Normalizes a tensor by `mean` and `variance`, and applies (optionally) a
  `scale` \\(\gamma\\) to it, as well as an `offset` \\(\beta\\):
  \\(\frac{\gamma(x-\mu)}{\sigma}+\beta\\)
  `mean`, `variance`, `offset` and `scale` are all expected to be of one of two
  shapes:
    * In all generality, they can have the same number of dimensions as the
      input `x`, with identical sizes as `x` for the dimensions that are not
      normalized over (the 'depth' dimension(s)), and dimension 1 for the
      others which are being normalized over.
      `mean` and `variance` in this case would typically be the outputs of
      `tf.nn.moments(..., keep_dims=True)` during training, or running averages
      thereof during inference.
    * In the common case where the 'depth' dimension is the last dimension in
      the input tensor `x`, they may be one dimensional tensors of the same
      size as the 'depth' dimension.
      This is the case for example for the common `[batch, depth]` layout of
      fully-connected layers, and `[batch, height, width, depth]` for
      convolutions.
      `mean` and `variance` in this case would typically be the outputs of
      `tf.nn.moments(..., keep_dims=False)` during training, or running averages
      thereof during inference.
  See Source: [Batch Normalization: Accelerating Deep Network Training by
  Reducing Internal Covariate Shift; S. Ioffe, C. Szegedy]
  (http://arxiv.org/abs/1502.03167).
  Args:
    x: Input `Tensor` of arbitrary dimensionality.
    mean: A mean `Tensor`.
    variance: A variance `Tensor`.
    offset: An offset `Tensor`, often denoted \\(\beta\\) in equations, or
      None. If present, will be added to the normalized tensor.
    scale: A scale `Tensor`, often denoted \\(\gamma\\) in equations, or
      `None`. If present, the scale is applied to the normalized tensor.
    variance_epsilon: A small float number to avoid dividing by 0.
    name: A name for this operation (optional).
  Returns:
    the normalized, scaled, offset tensor.
  """
  with ops.name_scope(name, "batchnorm", [x, mean, variance, scale, offset]):
    inv = math_ops.rsqrt(variance + variance_epsilon)
    if scale is not None:
      inv *= scale
    # Note: tensorflow/contrib/quantize/python/fold_batch_norms.py depends on
    # the precise order of ops that are generated by the expression below.
    return x * math_ops.cast(inv, x.dtype) + math_ops.cast(
        offset - mean * inv if offset is not None else -mean * inv, x.dtype)
```

I didn't understand how it works and could't convert to julia code. I'm using the same order for tensor shapes. If x has shape `[a,b,c]` in tf, it has `[a,b,c]` shape in my julia code aswell.

Comment: What package is `layer norm` part of?

Comment: ```layer_norm``` function belongs to ```tf.contrib.layers.layer_norm```

Answer (score 0):

`Flux` provides batch normalization and layer normalization (and some others) in Julia (called `LayerNorm` and `BatchNorm`. In your question you don't specify what library you use in Julia, but if you use something else than `Flux`, then the code might be helpful for your own implementation. See: https://github.com/FluxML/Flux.jl/blob/master/src/layers/normalise.jl

If you are using `Knet` (which I never did) there is at least batch normalization already implemented, I am not sure about other normalization layers. They might be there as well.

Please also post what you already tried so for in Julia.